# gorm: fetch relation later (without preloading)

Tags: go, lazy-loading, go-gorm

I know I can preload a relation defined in the model, but have not found any way how to load the relation later if I have an object which was not preloaded.

Sample:

```
type Template struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string
    UserID *uint
    User   *User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID"`
}
```

Now I can:

```
db.Preload("User").Find(&templates)
```

But what if I just want to fetch the User later?

```
db.First(&template)
assert.Nil(template.User)
//how to fetch the user now?
...
assert.NotNil(template.User)
```

thanks for tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [find associations](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Find-Associations) guide in the docs:

```
db.First(&template)
assert.Nil(template.User)
//how to fetch the user now?
db.Model(&template).Association("User").Find(template.User)
assert.NotNil(template.User)
```

Comment: just like this it throws "invalid value, should be pointer to struct or slice"
works, if I init the struct first:

   //how to fetch the user now?

  template.User = User{}
  db.Model(&template).Association("User").Find(template.User)